# What is the exact type of auto variable with multi-dim array in for-range in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

For comparison, let me state my understanding first. For one-dimensional array, `int arr[3]={1,2,3}`, we know that

1. `arr` is an array, which can decay to a pointer if wanted
2. `arr[0]` is the first element of the array
3. `&arr` is a pointer to 'entire' array, which has different behavior than `arr` under pointer arithmetic (c.f. `arr+1` and `(&arr)+1`).

Now, I wonder what exactly is the type of the `mat[0]` in:

```c
    int mat[2][3] = { {10, 20, 30}, {40, 50, 60} };
```

Is `mat[0]` something as 1, 2 or 3? I guess it was something as 1. But it proved that I was wrong because I found that:

```c
cout << *((&mat[0]) + 1); // not 40, but random address, say 000000AEE4EFF604
```

where I expected that `(&mat[0]) + 1` would point to the memory address of `40`. So is it case 3? But how?

Moreover, another harder problem is what type the iterator `it` in for-range exactly is. Again, does it belong to 1, 2, or 3?

```c
    for (auto it : mat) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Try `cout << **((&mat[0]) + 1);`

Comment: _"...is what type the iterator it in for-range exactly is.."_ - A trick in this situation is force a compilation error and the compiler will tell you what the type is - live -https://godbolt.org/z/YnPqdMx6x

Comment: @RichardCritten Wow, this technique is quite useful! Thanks!